# Get value from input on pageload

Tags: jquery

I like to display the value of the checked radio button in the span class active color. It works, but not on pageload. I have to check the second radio button to show the effect. I found a solution but I think it's not the best.

```
<span class="active-color"></span>

<div class="swatch-element">        
<input id="schwarz" type="radio" name="color" value="Schwarz" checked="checked">        
</div>

<div class="swatch-element">        
<input id="weiss" type="radio" name="color" value="weiss">        
</div>



$(".swatch-element input:radio").change(function(){
$('.active-color').text($(".swatch-element input:checked").val());
})
```

**My Solution**

```
$(".swatch-element input:radio").change(function(){
$('.active-color').text($(".swatch-element input:checked").val());
})  
$('.active-color').text($(".swatch-element input:checked").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've defined a `change` event handler, the easiest method is to simply trigger the `change` event, by calling the `change()` method with no arguments:

```
// the anonymous function binds the change event-handler:
$(".swatch-element input:radio").change(function(){
    $('.active-color').text($(".swatch-element input:checked").val());
// triggers the change event (which is then handled by the handler):
}).change();
```

It's worth noting that the `change` event is only fired when a radio input is checked, therefore within the anonymous function you can simply use `this`:

```
// the anonymous function binds the change event-handler:
$(".swatch-element input:radio").change(function(){
    $('.active-color').text(this.value);
// triggers the change event (which is then handled by the handler):
}).change();
```

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside document ready:

```
$(document).ready(
$(".swatch-element input:radio").change(function(){
$('.active-color').text($(".swatch-element input:checked").val());
})
```